# Spring Roo 1.3x web service call

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, spring-roo

I generate on application with Spring Roo 1.3 x.

I use 2 tables. Department and Employee.

generate spring mvc based application, using roo shell.

Now when I want to ADD an Employee, I want to call - some external web service (REST/SOAP) from my roo application --- against the ADD button operation.

In normal MVC application .. this is very easy ... but in spring roo - how can I achieve this for REST and  SOAP ?

Answer (score 0):

Note Spring Roo is a "development tool" that generates a "normal MVC application", you can customize it as needed.

You should customize or evolve it in the same way you would do with any Spring MVC application.